# how to sort results based on pivot table in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, pivot

i have three table like this :

- tour (id name) -> assume (id:1 , name : something)
- meta (id key) ->assume (id:1 , key: tour_duration)
- meta_tour (tour_id meta_id value) ->assume (tour_id:1 , meta_id:1 , value: 15)

it's ManyToMany relationship.

i want to sort tours based on meta value in meta_tour table like this :

```
tours orderBy tour_duration.value
```

**Update**

i tried this :

```
        Tour::with(['metas' => function ($query) {
        $query->where('key', 'tour_duration')
        ->orderByDesc('value');
        }])->paginate(15);
```

and this :

```
        Tour::with(['metas' => function ($query) {
        $query->where('key', 'tour_duration');
        }])->orderByDesc('value')->paginate(15);
```

and this :

```
        Tour::whereHas('metas' , function ($query) {
        $query->where('key', 'tour_duration')
              ->orderBy('value', 'desc')
        })->paginate(15);
```

but not working.

Comment: There is a little problem: You are trying to get a list of tours, but as you can have more than one meta per tour, you'd end up with lists where you have a duplicitiy of tours, and (I think) you cannot get this unless you query it up with a join

Comment: Thanks, can you show me a example of join? i'm new with this and i don't know how join tables based on my problem.

Comment: Do you want to get tours with multiple `meta_tour` entries multiple times? Or just once?

Comment: i want get all tours who have meta name "tour_duration".(each tour has one tour_duration) and sort tours with tour_duration value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a modified `withCount()`:

```php
Tour::withCount(['metas as tour_duration' => function ($query) {
    $query->select('meta_tour.value')->where('key', 'tour_duration');
}])->orderByDesc('tour_duration')->paginate(15);
```

This uses a subquery to get the `value` from the pivot table:

```sql
select `tours`.*,
  (select `meta_tour`.`value`
   from `metas`
   inner join `meta_tour` on `metas`.`id` = `meta_tour`.`meta_id`
   where `tours`.`id` = `meta_tour`.`tour_id`
     and `key` = 'tour_duration') as `tour_duration`
from `tours`
order by `tour_duration` desc
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `withPivot` method to order by a pivot table column:

```
// Tour model
public function meta () {
    return $this->belongsToMany(Meta::class)
                ->withPivot('meta_tour')
                ->orderByDesc('meta_tour.value');
}
```

**Update**

To only get the meta with tour duration, try eager loading and adding a where clause on the meta:

```
$tour->with(['meta' => function ($query) {
    $query->where('key', 'tour_duration');
}])->orderByDesc('meta.value')->get();
```

Comment: it's not working .. i want sort by tour_duration value not every items value.

Comment: I added another example that would limit the meta being queried.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```php
Tour::join('meta_tour', 'meta_tour.tour_id', '=', 'tour.id')
    ->join('meta', 'meta_tour.meta_id', '=', 'meta.id')
    ->where('meta.key', '=', 'tour_duration')
    ->orderBy('meta_tour.value', 'DESC')
    ->get();
```